# Extracting all levels of a NetCDF file and exporting as multiband raster

Tags: raster, r, netcdf, stack, rasterbrick

I am trying to convert this .nc file with land cover data from ESA CCI (http://maps.elie.ucl.ac.be/CCI/viewer/download.php). There is a separate .nc file for each year, and each file contains the variables lccs_class, processed_flag, current_pixel_state, observation_count and change_count.

I would like to open each of these files in R and export them as a multiband raster with a band for each variable (one multiband raster per year).

However, whenever I try to read these files in using brick() or stack() the nlayers are always 1. If I dont specify a variable with varname, the name listed is the date of the file (e.g. 2016-01-01).

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(ncdf4)

# using stack
test <- stack("ESA_CCI_LC_2016_2019/C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.1.1.nc",varname="lccs_class")
test
```

The output is

```
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 64800, 129600, 8398080000, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.002777778, 0.002777778  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
names      : Land.cover.class.defined.in.LCCS
```

I am not sure of the best way to get the output I need when each .nc file represents a single year (not time series data). I have tried playing around with the levels argument and lvar in the raster brick function but haven't had any luck.

gdalinfo output below

```
[1] "Warning 1: Recode from UTF-8 to CP_ACP failed with the error: \"Invalid argument\"."                                                                                                                   
 [2] "Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format"                                                                                                                                                             
 [3] "Files: ESA_CCI_LC_2016_2019/C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.1.1.nc"                                                                                                                                
 [4] "       ESA_CCI_LC_2016_2019/C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.1.1.nc.aux.xml"                                                                                                                        
 [5] "Size is 512, 512"                                                                                                                                                                                      
 [6] "Metadata:"                                                                                                                                                                                             
 [7] "  NC_GLOBAL#cdm_data_type=grid"                                                                                                                                                                        
 [8] "  NC_GLOBAL#comment="                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [9] "  NC_GLOBAL#contact=copernicus-support@ecmwf.int"                                                                                                                                                      
[10] "  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.6"                                                                                                                                                                        
[11] "  NC_GLOBAL#creation_date=20181130T105436Z"                                                                                                                                                            
[12] "  NC_GLOBAL#creator_email=landcover-cci@uclouvain.be"                                                                                                                                                  
[13] "  NC_GLOBAL#creator_name=UCLouvain"                                                                                                                                                                    
[14] "  NC_GLOBAL#creator_url=http://www.uclouvain.be/"                                                                                                                                                      
[15] "  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_max=90.0"                                                                                                                                                                   
[16] "  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_min=-90.0"                                                                                                                                                                  
[17] "  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_resolution=0.002778"                                                                                                                                                        
[18] "  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_units=degrees_north"                                                                                                                                                        
[19] "  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_max=null"                                                                                                                                                                   
[20] "  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_min=null"                                                                                                                                                                   
[21] "  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_resolution=0.002778"                                                                                                                                                        
[22] "  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_units=degrees_east"                                                                                                                                                         
[23] "  NC_GLOBAL#history=lc-sr-1.0, lc-classification-1.0,lc-user-tools-3.14,lc-user-tools-4.3"                                                                                                             
[24] "  NC_GLOBAL#id=C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.1.1"                                                                                                                                                
[25] "  NC_GLOBAL#institution=UCLouvain"                                                                                                                                                                     
[26] "  NC_GLOBAL#keywords=land cover classification,satellite,observation"                                                                                                                                  
[27] "  NC_GLOBAL#keywords_vocabulary=NASA Global Change Master Directory (GCMD) Science Keywords"                                                                                                           
[28] "  NC_GLOBAL#license=EC C3S Land cover Data Policy"                                                                                                                                                     
[29] "  NC_GLOBAL#naming_authority="                                                                                                                                                                         
[30] "  NC_GLOBAL#product_version=2.1.1"                                                                                                                                                                     
[31] "  NC_GLOBAL#project=EC C3S Land cover"                                                                                                                                                                 
[32] "  NC_GLOBAL#references=https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/"                                                                                                                                             
[33] "  NC_GLOBAL#source=PROBA-V"                                                                                                                                                                            
[34] "  NC_GLOBAL#spatial_resolution=300m"                                                                                                                                                                   
[35] "  NC_GLOBAL#standard_name_vocabulary=NetCDF Climate and Forecast (CF) Standard Names version 21"                                                                                                       
[36] "  NC_GLOBAL#summary=This dataset characterizes the land cover of a particular year (see time_coverage). The land cover was derived from the analysis of satellite data time series of the full period."
[37] "  NC_GLOBAL#TileSize=2025:2025"                                                                                                                                                                        
[38] "  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_duration=P1Y"                                                                                                                                                                
[39] "  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_end=20161231"                                                                                                                                                                
[40] "  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_resolution=P1Y"                                                                                                                                                              
[41] "  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_start=20160101"                                                                                                                                                              
[42] "  NC_GLOBAL#title=Land Cover Map of 2016"                                                                                                                                                              
[43] "  NC_GLOBAL#tracking_id=1c3c8172-906d-4ce0-9aa7-f3a9d9b4e021"                                                                                                                                          
[44] "  NC_GLOBAL#type=C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y"                                                                                                                                                          
[45] "Subdatasets:"                                                                                                                                                                                          
[46] "  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=NETCDF:\"ESA_CCI_LC_2016_2019/C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.1.1.nc\":lccs_class"                                                                                             
[47] "  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[1x64800x129600] land_cover_lccs (8-bit unsigned integer)"                                                                                                                         
[48] "  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=NETCDF:\"ESA_CCI_LC_2016_2019/C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.1.1.nc\":processed_flag"                                                                                         
[49] "  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[1x64800x129600] land_cover_lccs status_flag (8-bit integer)"                                                                                                                      
[50] "  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=NETCDF:\"ESA_CCI_LC_2016_2019/C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.1.1.nc\":current_pixel_state"                                                                                    
[51] "  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[1x64800x129600] land_cover_lccs status_flag (8-bit integer)"                                                                                                                      
[52] "  SUBDATASET_4_NAME=NETCDF:\"ESA_CCI_LC_2016_2019/C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.1.1.nc\":observation_count"                                                                                      
[53] "  SUBDATASET_4_DESC=[1x64800x129600] land_cover_lccs number_of_observations (16-bit unsigned integer)"                                                                                                 
[54] "  SUBDATASET_5_NAME=NETCDF:\"ESA_CCI_LC_2016_2019/C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.1.1.nc\":change_count"                                                                                           
[55] "  SUBDATASET_5_DESC=[1x64800x129600] change_count (8-bit unsigned integer)"                                                                                                                            
[56] "  SUBDATASET_6_NAME=NETCDF:\"ESA_CCI_LC_2016_2019/C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.1.1.nc\":lat_bounds"                                                                                             
[57] "  SUBDATASET_6_DESC=[64800x2] lat_bounds (64-bit floating-point)"                                                                                                                                      
[58] "  SUBDATASET_7_NAME=NETCDF:\"ESA_CCI_LC_2016_2019/C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.1.1.nc\":lon_bounds"                                                                                             
[59] "  SUBDATASET_7_DESC=[129600x2] lon_bounds (64-bit floating-point)"                                                                                                                                     
[60] "  SUBDATASET_8_NAME=NETCDF:\"ESA_CCI_LC_2016_2019/C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.1.1.nc\":time_bounds"                                                                                            
[61] "  SUBDATASET_8_DESC=[1x2] time_bounds (64-bit floating-point)"                                                                                                                                         
[62] "Corner Coordinates:"                                                                                                                                                                                   
[63] "Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)"                                                                                                                                                                         
[64] "Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)"                                                                                                                                                                         
[65] "Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)"                                                                                                                                                                         
[66] "Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)"                                                                                                                                                                         
[67] "Center      (  256.0,  256.0)"
```

Comment: These look like *very* large rasters so I think R is going to struggle. The files looks like they are many Gb and that will take forever on my home network. What does `gdalInfo` from the `gdalUtils` package say about the files?

Comment: Hi @Spacedman Yes, these are very large files (I need global layers) I think they are about 2.5GB on my desktop computer. I have tried using your suggestion but get an error message. 

ESA_dataset <- system.file("ESA_CCI_LC_2016_2019/C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.1.1.nc", package="gdalUtils")
gdalinfo(ESA_dataset,verbose=TRUE)

Gives: ERROR 4: : No such file or directorygdalinfo failed - unable to open ''.

Comment: Not sure why you've used `system.file` - that is trying to get a file from the `gdalUtils` package which I suspect you've copied from the help. Give it the path to your file - `gdalInfo("ESA_CCI_LC_2016_2019/C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.1.1.nc")` - if that works edit your question and add the info up there^^^

Comment: Hi @Spacedman thanks for your comment, I have added the output above